# WCF Service exporting 1 Interface with 2 Implementation classes

Tags: c#, wcf, interface

I'm new to WCF and C#.

I'm trying to create a WCF Service with 1 Interface (IA) with 1 method (Do) which has 2 implementations (A1 & A2).

A silly example:

**IA.cs:**

```
namespace IA_NS
{
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface IA
    {
        [OperationContract]
        int Do(B b);
    }

    [DataContract]
    public class B
    {
        [DataMember]
        public string b1 { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**A1.cs:**

```
namespace A1_NS
{
    public class A1 : IA
    {
        public int Do(B b) {...}
    }
}
```

**A2.cs:**

```
namespace A2_NS
{
    public class A2 : IA
    {
        public int Do(B b) {...}
    }
}
```

**My Self-Hosting-Console, where I host both services:**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ServiceHost hostA1 = new ServiceHost(typeof(A1_NS.A1));
        hostA1.Open();
        ServiceHost hostA2 = new ServiceHost(typeof(A2_NS.A2));
        hostA2.Open();
        Console.WriteLine("Hit any key to exit...");
        Console.ReadLine();
        hostA1.Close();
        hostA2.Close();
    }
}
```

I want my WCF Client to be able to call both classes:

**Client.cs:**

```
namespace Client_NS
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            B myB = new B();
            A1 a1 = new A1();
            A2 a2 = new A2();
            A1.Do(myB);
            A2.Do(myB);
        }
    }
}
```

No luck ;-(

I tried putting 2  elements in my WCF-Service **app.config**:

```
<service name="A1_NS.A1" >
    <endpoint address="http://localhost/A1"
              contract="IA_NS.IA" />
</service>
<service name="A2_NS.A2" >
    <endpoint address="http://localhost/A2"
              contract="IA_NS.IA" />
</service>
```

When running the debugger - the debugging app (WCF Service Host) lets me test the Do() method of both classes.

I can't get my Client to do it. I added Service References for both services.
Is it the Client app.config  or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: Is your error actually reading "No luck ;-("? Because without knowing what your problem is, it's hard to suggest a solution. Please be more precise regarding the problem you have.

Comment: please post the code of where you initialize the wcf services in the client. most likely where your problem is ...

Comment: nvoigt - "No luck" means I would appreciate some guidance as of where to look and what to post.

Comment: @RamiRosenbaum post the code in static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ...
            B myB;
where your client connects to the WCF services ...

Comment: Omribitan - I'm not sure I'm using the WCF correctly.
Is using 2 <service> elements correct? Or 2 <endpoint> elements?
To declare an object of class B I need to specifically choose WCFClient.ServiceReferenceA1.B or WCFClient.ServiceReferenceA2.B.

Give me a minute, I'll create a project with those names

Comment: @RamiRosenbaum There is no problem using 2 services that implement the same contract. there is also no problem using two different endpoints for the two different services. If you are using  WCF with Service References, each service should have a unique name so you can contact it. when you create each reference visual studio automatically produces different endpoints for each service. If you understand hebrew (My guess by your name), I suggest you read this post : http://webmaster.org.il/articles/wcf-communicate-with-service

Comment: I've added the Host code and updated the Client code.
My problem is that B (of the client) code is ambiguous:
error CS0104: 'B' is an ambiguous reference between 'WCFClient.ServiceReferenceA1.B' and 'WCFClient.ServiceReferenceA2.B'

Comment: Omribitan - Thanks, I'll have a look now. גמר חתימה...

Comment: I think this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2327137/multiple-wcf-services-referencing-the-same-data-contracts) is a better description of my problem: 2 services referencing the same data contract.
The solutions are not elegant enough...

Answer (score 1):

You could implement **partial classes** that allow you to separate your content in individual cs files while maintaing a single interface and endpoint. This isn't the most ideal way, because at the end of the day it is still a single class made up of partial classes, but at least it looks like it in your file structure, thus giving some separation rather than a massive class file.

## Example Structure:

**IMyService.cs**

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IMyService
{
   [OperationContract]
   string GenericMethod()

   [OperationContract]
   string GetA(int id)

   [OperationContract]
   string GetB(int id)

}
```

**MyService.cs**

```
//Put any attributes for your service in this class file
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public partial class MyService : IMyService
{
  public string GenericMethod() 
  {
     return "";
  }
}
```

**AService.cs**

```
public partial class MyService
{
    public string GetA(int id) 
    {
       return "";
    }
}
```

**BService.cs**

```
public partial class MyService
{
      public string GetB(int id) 
      {
          return "";
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I see contract twice (under `A2_NS.A2` service tag), is that by mistake or if it's really there, then remove 2nd one(after closing endpoint tag) and see if this was related to issues you were getting?

```
contract="IA_NS.IA" />
    contract="IA_NS.IA" />
```

Comment: That was a typo, fixed, thanks.
I learned that my problem was actually: [2 services referencing the same data contract](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2327137/multiple-wcf-services-referencing-the-same-data-contracts)